# Full access to the files on my Samba share

Tags: debian, permissions, samba

I download files with my Nas Server with Debian on it to a path. this path is also shared with SMB to a Windows PC. Now when I try to delete some files on my Nas from Windows I get permission errors.

I set the permission to access all files but with new files I have to set the permissions again and again for the files containing these path!

These new files are downloaded with these user/group download:downloadgr with these permissions 0755.

What can I do to keep full access to these path and the containing files from my PC after download.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ACLs:

```
setfacl -R -m d:u:youruser:rwx /your/dir
setfacl -R -m u:youruser:rwx /your/dir
```

The first command sets the default ACLs (for new files) to `rwx` for `youruser` recursively in `/your/dir`. The second command does the same for the currently existing files.